# boost::thread and std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, c++11

Is it somehow possible to pass an std::unique_ptr as a parameter to a boost::thread constructor? If not, what is the best workaround?

A small example:

```
// errors: g++ uniqueptr_thread.cpp -std=c++0x

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class TestThread{
public:
  void operator()(std::unique_ptr<int> val){
    std::cout << "parameter: " << val << std::endl;
  }

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int(5));

  boost::thread th( new TestThread(), std::move(ptr));

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles and runs for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

class TestThread{
public:
  void operator()(std::unique_ptr<int> val){
    std::cout << "parameter: " << *val << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{

  std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int(5));

  std::thread th( TestThread(), std::move(ptr));
  th.join();

}
```

But it has to be in C++0x mode.  I don't know if the boost move emulation is good enough to do this or not.

Comment: with which compiler? g++ 4.4.5 gives me longer error list than the boost version, using the same options (-std=c++0x)

Comment: @Dutwo: According to C++0x, it should work. If it doesn't, then it's probably something wrong with your version of GCC or libc++. Perhaps try a more recent one?

Comment: I used clang + libc++ (http://llvm.org/), pretty close to tip-of-development trunk for both of them, on Mac OS X.

Comment: This does not compile in GCC4.6 either. My naive guess at the moment is that it is because `std::bind` removes references, and that there is no rvalue-reference wrapper. Indeed, using the `make_adv` construction [from this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126219/is-there-a-reference-wrapper-for-rvalue-references) I can make it compile, but I get a `system_error` exception at runtime.

Comment: fails to build in VS2013

Answer (score 2):

A std::unique_ptr is, as the name suggests, *unique*. **There can be only one!**

Now, if your thread function takes a std::unique_ptr&&, and you use std::move to move the parameter in the thread function, *then* you can pass the std::unique_ptr. But then your copy will be empty, since you moved it to the other thread.

If std::move does not work, then your compiler or standard library may have bugs in it. I imagine that transferring ownership across threads like this isn't a common occurrence. And C++11 is still fairly new.

Comment: +1.  I suspect moving it to the other thread is what he wanted.  This looks like a clean way to pass an arbitrary object to a thread.

Comment: sorry, I forgot std::move from the example code, it was there in the original, but it still won't compile

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your problem is with the unique_ptr?  Why does your example use new to create your functor? That line should just read:

```
boost::thread th(TestThread(), std::move(ptr));
```