# C++1y no viable conversion from std::bind to std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying to store a forward function into `std::function`. If I use `std::bind`, I get error message like `no viable conversion from ...`. If I use lambda, it compile okay.

Here is sample code

```
#include <functional>

template<typename Handler>void func1(int a, Handler&& handler) {}
template<typename Handler>void func2(Handler&& handler)
{
    // this line compile fine
    std::function<void ()> funcA = [handler = std::move(handler)]() { func1(1, std::move(handler)); };
    // this line got compile error
    std::function<void ()> funcB = std::bind(func1<Handler>, 1, std::move(handler));
}

int main()
{
    func2(&main); // this just a sample, I am using functor as argument in real code
}
```

Trying both **g++ --std=c++1y** (v4.9.0) and **clang++ --std=c++1y** (v3.4.1) yield the same result

edit: clang++ error message

```
main.cpp:8:28: error: no viable conversion from 'typename _Bind_helper<__is_socketlike<void (*)(int, int (*&&)())>::value, void (*)(int, int
      (*&&)()), int, int (*)()>::type' (aka '_Bind<__func_type (typename decay<int>::type, typename decay<int (*)()>::type)>') to
      'std::function<void ()>'
    std::function<void ()> funcB = std::bind(&func1<Handler>, 1, std::move(handler));
                           ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:14:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'func2<int (*)()>' requested here
    func2(&main);
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0/../../../../include/c++/4.9.0/functional:2181:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no
      known conversion from 'typename _Bind_helper<__is_socketlike<void (*)(int, int (*&&)())>::value, void (*)(int, int (*&&)()), int, int
      (*)()>::type' (aka '_Bind<__func_type (typename decay<int>::type, typename decay<int (*)()>::type)>') to 'nullptr_t' for 1st argument
      function(nullptr_t) noexcept
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0/../../../../include/c++/4.9.0/functional:2192:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no
      known conversion from 'typename _Bind_helper<__is_socketlike<void (*)(int, int (*&&)())>::value, void (*)(int, int (*&&)()), int, int
      (*)()>::type' (aka '_Bind<__func_type (typename decay<int>::type, typename decay<int (*)()>::type)>') to 'const std::function<void ()> &'
      for 1st argument
      function(const function& __x);
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0/../../../../include/c++/4.9.0/functional:2201:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no
      known conversion from 'typename _Bind_helper<__is_socketlike<void (*)(int, int (*&&)())>::value, void (*)(int, int (*&&)()), int, int
      (*)()>::type' (aka '_Bind<__func_type (typename decay<int>::type, typename decay<int (*)()>::type)>') to 'std::function<void ()> &&' for
      1st argument
      function(function&& __x) : _Function_base()
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0/../../../../include/c++/4.9.0/functional:2226:2: note: candidate template ignored:
      substitution failure [with _Functor = std::_Bind<void (*(int, int (*)()))(int, int (*&&)())>]: no matching function for call to object of
      type 'std::_Bind<void (*(int, int (*)()))(int, int (*&&)())>'
        function(_Functor);
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Please post the full error message, with notes and all.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the first line doesn't seem to compile if you use clang with `-stdlib=libc++`.

Comment: The problem is with your rvalue reference, [here's a tersely answered question on how to get that to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126219/is-there-a-reference-wrapper-for-rvalue-references).

Comment: BTW, for questions like this, you get a more useful diagnostic if you attempt to invoke the result of `std::bind` directly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### INTRODUCTION

*std::bind* will try to call `func1<Handler>` with an *lvalue-reference*, but your instantiation of *func1* will make it only accept *rvalues*.

---

#### EXPLANATION

Here we have reduced your testcase to the bare minimum to show what is going on, the snippet below is ill-formed and an explanation will follow to why that is.

```
#include <functional>

template<class T>
void foobar (T&& val);

int main() {
  std::function<void()> f = std::bind (&foobar<int>, std::move (123));
}
```

In the above we will instantiate `foobar` with `T = int`, which makes the type of argument *val* to be an *rvalue-reference* to *int* (`int&&`).

`std::move(123)` will *move-construct* our value to be stored inside the object created by *std::bind*, but the Standard says that when *std::bind* later invokes the stored function, all arguments are passed as `TiD cv &`; ie. as *lvalues*.

This behavior is mandated by the Standard ([n3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)), as stated in section `[func.bind.bind]p10`.

By changing the previous ill-formed snippet into the following, no error will be raised, since `foobar<int>` now accepts an *lvalue-reference*; suitable to be bound to the *lvalue* passed to our function by the *function-object* returned by *std::bind*.

```
  std::function<void()> f = std::bind (&foobar<int&>, std::move (123));
```

---

#### ???

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  auto is_lvalue = [](auto&& x) {
    return std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype(x)> { };
  };

  auto check = std::bind (is_lvalue, std::move (123));
  bool res   = check (); // res = true
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. So there is no way to move variable(s) by using **std::bind**? The only way is C++1y generic lambda (which cannot use in my production code, sadly).

Comment: @user3724853 you could create a wrapper that would yield an rvalue-reference through a *conversion-function*, but one has to be **very** careful if the resulting *function-object* will be called more than once (since you have effectively already moved from the wrapped object).

Comment: This makes me wonder if one-shot lambda syntax might be useful -- `&&` qualified `operator()` only.  A `&&` qualified overload for all lambdas that treat class-locals like locals.  And a way to extract the r-l value of the context a lambda was called in to conditionally forward data.

Answer (score 2):

in short: `function` has to be copyable. `bind` with rvalue returns non-copyable object. Workaround is to capture/bind with `shared_ptr` containing abovementioned value