# Problems using std::unique_ptr with std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I am trying to pass a std::unique_ptr (of array type) through a std::bind and I am getting compiler errors.

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

class PrintClass 
{ 
public:
    void printFunc(std::unique_ptr<char[]> text) 
    {
        printf("Printed text %s\n", text.get());
    }
};


int main() 
{
    std::unique_ptr<PrintClass> printObj(new PrintClass);
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[1024]);
    strcpy(buffer.get(),"Test data"); 
    std::function<void()> fn = std::bind(&PrintClass::printFunc,
        printObj.get(), std::move(buffer));
    fn();
}
```

This returns the following compiler error:

> test.cpp: In function `int main()`:
>   test.cpp:21:98: error: conversion from `std::_Bind_helper<false, void (PrintClass::*)(std::unique_ptr<char []>), PrintClass*, std::unique_ptr<char [], std::default_delete<char []> > >::type {aka std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (PrintClass::*)(std::unique_ptr<char []>)>(PrintClass*, std::unique_ptr<char []>)>}` to non-scalar type `std::function<void()>` requested
>       std::function fn = std::bind(&PrintClass::printFunc,printObj.get(), >std::move(buffer));

I am compiling with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 ...
```

I could use raw pointers but I then run the risk of memory leaks. So how do I pass ownership of my buffer through the std::bind interface?

I am using strings here to illustrate my point. My real problem involves passing binary memory buffers which I want to ensure do not leak.

Please ignore the use of strcpy without array bounds checking, I just wanted to knock something together to illustrate my problem.

Comment: Related to [Is there a reference_wrapper<> for rvalue references?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126219/is-there-a-reference-wrapper-for-rvalue-references?lq=1)

Comment: Since unique_ptr does not have a copy constructor, shouldn't your function take an rvalue reference ?

Comment: Related enough to be a dupe, I think. Good question, though.

Comment: There's a secondary issue, in that you're attempting to assign a move-only `bind` (due to the unique_ptr's being stored at bind time) to a `std::function`, which requires that the function objects be copyable.