# Is there a mutable version of std::bind?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, immutability

I'm trying to `std::bind` a `std::move` on a `std::unique_ptr`. The resulting function object seems to be immutable, so it would be impossible to perform the move when the functor is invoked.

I suspect this is because of the same reason why lambdas are immutable by default - invoking them should do the same thing every time. However there are cases where they need to be mutable, which is why we have the `mutable` keyword.

```cpp
void foo(std::unique_ptr<int>&& ptr)
{
    cout << *ptr << endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_unique<int>(123);
    std::bind(foo, std::move(ptr))();             // Doesn't compile
    [&ptr]() { foo(std::move(ptr)); }();          // Equivalent, doesn't compile
    [&ptr]() mutable { foo(std::move(ptr)); }();  // Compiles
    return 0;
}
```

Instad of using `bind` I could wrap a function call in a mutable lambda. However at least to me personally `bind` looks much cleaner and simpler in this case.

I understand that invoking the mutable lambda twice would lead to undefined behavior, because I would be moving again from an already moved-from pointer. But in my case I know the functor will only be called once.

Is there a way I could use `std::bind` to do this? Is there a `bind_mutable` of sorts? If not, how should I go about writing it myself?

Comment: Your claim is wrong, both lambda works: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b21ee8e7d660955b). What you would need for bind would be a `rvalue_refence_wrapper`. See [is-there-a-reference-wrapper-for-rvalue-references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126219/is-there-a-reference-wrapper-for-rvalue-references).

Comment: Are you actually stuck in [tag:C++11], or does your compiler have some [tag:C++14] features?  Because the need for `bind` here is basically gone in [tag:C++14].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However at least to me personally bind looks much cleaner and simpler in this case.

Do not use `std::bind` in C++11. Use lambdas instead. `std::bind` has several issues [excellently explained in this talk by Stephan T. Lavavej **“functional: What's New, And Proper Usage"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt7ThwVfap0).

[image: screenshot from talk]

It might look simpler and cleaner in this case, but it's not recommended.

Writing...

```
[&ptr]{ foo(std::move(ptr)); }();
```

...is the proper way of solving this problem.

Comment: `[&ptr]() { foo(std::move(ptr)); }();` is enough BTW.

Comment: That downside of the `&ptr` syntax is that your lambda cannot be copied/moved out of the current stack context.  C++14 solves this.