# std::bind with a movable paramter

Tags: c++11

I am having trouble with `std::bind` and using a moveable type as a parameter. Is read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871273/passing-rvalues-through-stdbind) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126219/is-there-a-reference-wrapper-for-rvalue-references?lq=1), but in those cases I actually see the issue since there the OP want's to have a rvalue reference inside the bind. What I want to is have a lvalue, but just to move-construct it when calling `std::bind`. Here is a minimal sample:

```
#include <functional>

struct Foo
{
    using Callback = std::function<void(int)>;

    void Do(const Callback &callback)
    {
        callback(5);
    }
};

class Param
{
private:
    Param() {};

public:
    Param(Param&&)
    {
    }

    // commenting out copy ctor triggers the last two invocations in Bar() to fail
#if 1   
    Param(const Param&)
    {
    }
#endif

    Param& operator=(Param&&)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    static Param Create()
    {
        return Param();
    }

    int value_ = 10;
};

struct Bar
{
    Bar()
    {
        Foo f;
        f.Do(std::bind(&Bar::Callback1, this, std::placeholders::_1));
        Param p(Param::Create());
        f.Do(std::bind(&Bar::Callback2, this, std::move(p), std::placeholders::_1)); // does not work w/o copy ctor
        f.Do(std::bind<decltype(&Bar::Callback2), Bar*, Param>(&Bar::Callback2, this, std::move(p), std::placeholders::_1)); // does not work w/o copy ctor
    }

    void Callback1(int a)
    {
        printf("%d\n", a);
    }

    void Callback2(const Param &p, int a)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", a, p.value_);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar b;
}
```

So I want `Param` to be move constructible - as shown in the comments adding a copy ctor solves everything (and if everything else fails I will just go that way). The only thing that from my point of view could prohibit this is if the result of `std::bind` must be copy constructible, but [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) states:

> The return type of std::bind is CopyConstructible if all of its member objects (specified above) are CopyConstructible, and is MoveConstructible otherwise.

I thought that if the type how the variable is stored in the bind is deduced from the call then `std::move` could cause an attempt to store a rvalue reference, thus the second call where I explicitly state the template parameters (and would expect the bind itself to have a member of type `Param` which is move constructible and move assignable).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your troubles come from `std::function`.

`std::bind` returns some callable which has `Param` as member variable. When `std::function` instance is created all members of that functor generated by `bind` are stored **by copying**. When copy constructor of `Param` is commented out, it is just not possible to create `std::function` wrapper. And this is your issue.

As solution, get rid of `std::function`, and just pass any callable as template parameter:

```
template<class F>
void Do(F&& callback)
{
    callback(5);
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/R_QVwU)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly, I can't use this approach, since I actually have a class that takes a std::function callback, and I just wanted to bind my member function with extra parameters as that callback. I'll just adjust it to become copyable, still this seems weird. Is there any chance std::function will be improved to allow this?