# rvalue reference to boost asio completion handler

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio, rvalue-reference

In boost::asio, is it possible to use move semantics and rvalue reference emulation in C++11 to create and implement completion handlers?

My attempt is below, but I don't understand the reason for the errors I am getting:

Class Definition:

```
struct SocketTest : std::enable_shared_from_this<SocketTest> {


  SocketTest(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket):socket_(std::move(socket)){}

  template<typename Handler>
  void async_receive(dummy dummy,Handler&& handler){
    auto self(shared_from_this());

    socket_.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buf_), 
       std::bind([this,self](
          boost::system::error_code ec, 
          std::size_t bytes_transferred, 
          Handler&& moved_handler
       ){
           moved_handler(ec,bytes_transferred);
        }, std::move(handler)));

  }

  std::array<char,max_length> buf_;
  boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
};
```

Example of calling the class:

```
SocketTest socket_test(std::move(s));

socket_test.async_receive(dummy(), []( boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred){
    // many cool things accomplished!
});
```

It seems the version below which copies the handler works correctly, but I am interested in learning how to avoid that copy:

```
struct SocketTest : std::enable_shared_from_this<SocketTest> {


  SocketTest(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket):socket_(std::move(socket)){}

  template<typename Handler>
  void async_receive(dummy dummy,Handler handler){
    auto self(shared_from_this());

    socket_.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buf_), [this,self,handler](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred){
       handler(ec,bytes_transferred);

    });

  }

  std::array<char,max_length> buf_;
  boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
};
```

[The full source and errors can be found here](https://gist.github.com/ahundt/7cad089bb7960ca987c1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `bind` to a callable object taking rvalue reference because when `bind` saves its argument, it's not an rvalue anymore. In your case you can just make it accept `Handler` by value (and this is the final place where the handler is stored). You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4871273/3959454) for further details.

Also, you forgot to provide placeholders to `bind`:

```
socket_.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buf_), 
   std::bind([this,self](
      boost::system::error_code ec, 
      std::size_t bytes_transferred, 
      Handler moved_handler
   // ^^^^^^^ passing by value 
   ){
       moved_handler(ec,bytes_transferred);
    }, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::move(handler)));
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ placeholders added
```