# Template class overload std::bind a member fucntion

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

Somebody can help me to build this source code in a right way,
I understand that I shold declare the callBack as `std::function<void(std::unique_ptr<int>&& param)>` because this take a no copy
constructible param(`std::unique_ptr`), so what is the correct type if I no use auto to deduce the type?

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

template <class T>
class SomeClass {
  void someFunctionCallback(float o) = 0;
};

template <>
class SomeClass<float> {
 public:
  SomeClass() = default;
  inline void someFunction() {
      // std::function<void()>
    auto callBack {
     std::move(std::bind(&SomeClass<float>::someFunctionCallback,
                         this,
                         std::unique_ptr<int>{new int(9)}))};
     useCallBack(std::move(callBack));
  }
  inline void someFunctionCallback(std::unique_ptr<int>&& param) {
  }
  inline void useCallBack(std::function<void()> &&callBack) {
//    callBack();
  }
};
int main() {
  SomeClass<float> k;
  k.someFunction();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a couple of problems. First, `auto { ... }` will deduce an `std::initializer_list`. That's not what you want. Use a *brace-or-equal* initializer instead.

```
auto callBack =
 std::bind(&SomeClass<float>::someFunctionCallback,
                     this,
                     std::unique_ptr<int>{new int(9)});
```

Second, your function takes an rvalue-reference, but `std::bind` will pass an lvalue. Read [Passing rvalues through std::bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871273/passing-rvalues-through-stdbind) for a full explanation, but as a workaround you can use this ugly cast:

```
using uptr = std::unique_ptr<int>;

auto callBack =
 std::bind(&SomeClass<float>::someFunctionCallback,
                     this,
                     std::bind(static_cast<uptr&&(&)(uptr&)>(std::move<uptr&>), 
                               std::unique_ptr<int>{new int(9)})
          ) ;
```

Finally, just make your function a template. The whole idea is not to worry about the type, and `auto` follows the rules of template argument deduction anyway.

```
template <typename T>
inline void useCallBack(T callBack) {
  callBack();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
I have other qustion if I know the type(for example callBack) is recommended use std::initializer_list({}) if I no worry of the type and use auto then I should use the other way that you say me previously?