# Error while appling std::bind to function with argument <boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

There's a function accepting an argument with type `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket`. But I failed to apply std::bind to it. I've checked template arguments in std::_Bind_helper but no problem found. I've tried both gcc 8.1.0 and clang 6.0.0, and they give the same error.

```
#include <functional>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using namespace std;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using tcp = asio::ip::tcp;

int c;

void good_f(int) {c=1;}
void good() {
    using typeA = int;

    auto helper = std::bind(&good_f, typeA(1));
    helper();
    // OK
}

void fixed_f(tcp::socket &) {c=1;}
void fixed() {
    using type1 = tcp::socket;
    asio::io_context ioc;
    tcp::socket sock(ioc);

    auto helper = std::bind(&fixed_f, std::ref(sock));
    helper();
    // OK
}

void fail_f(tcp::socket &&) {c=1;}
void fail() {
    using type1 = tcp::socket;
    asio::io_context ioc;
    tcp::socket sock(ioc);

    // fail_f(std::move(sock));
    // OK

    auto helper = std::bind(&fail_f, std::move(sock));
    helper();
    // a.cc:34:5: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'std::_Bind<void (*(boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>))(boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> &&)>'
    //    helper();
    //    ^~~~~~
}
```

Compilation log and errors:

```
recolic@RECOLICPC ~/tmp> clang++ --version
clang version 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
recolic@RECOLICPC ~/tmp> clang++ -c a.cc
a.cc:39:5: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'std::_Bind<void (*(boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>))(boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> &&)>'
    helper();
    ^~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/functional:480:2: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Args = <>]: no type named 'type' in 'std::result_of<void
      (*&(boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> &))(boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> &&)>'
        operator()(_Args&&... __args)
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/functional:491:2: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Args = <>]: no type named 'type' in 'std::result_of<void (*const &(const
      boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> &))(boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> &&)>'
        operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/functional:509:2: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Args = <>]: no type named 'type' in 'std::result_of<void (*volatile &(volatile
      boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> &))(boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> &&)>'
        operator()(_Args&&... __args) volatile
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/functional:521:2: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Args = <>]: no type named 'type' in 'std::result_of<void (*const volatile &(const volatile
      boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> &))(boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> &&)>'
        operator()(_Args&&... __args) const volatile
        ^
1 error generated.
```

I'm not sure what caused this error. Could you please give me any suggestions?

Comment: Write `auto f = std::bind(something);`

Comment: @PasserBy I already tried but it doesn't help. The return type is exactly what I wrote here.

Comment: [`boost::ip::tcp::socket`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html) is not copy constructible/assignable, so `fail_f` needs to accepts its arg by reference rather than by value.  Also, make use of `auto` as suggested by @PasserBy.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks a lot and it works. However, I tried another solution (by right-value reference) `void fail_f(tcp::socket &&)`+`std::move(tcp::socket(ioc))` and I'm not sure why it fails. Could you please [view it](https://s.recn.pw/d.html) again?

Comment: Bound arguments are always passed as lvalues.

Comment: @RecolicKeghart Please removed the "solved" from your title, then add your solution as an answer. Stackoverflow is _not_ a forum.

Comment: This is a Q&A. If you have an A, post an A. Don't add an A to the Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void fail_f_1(tcp::socket);
std::bind(&fail_f_1, tcp::socket(io_context));`
 
This solution fails because `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` is noncopyable.

`void fail_f_2(tcp::socket &&);
std::bind(&fail_f_2, std::move(tcp::socket(io_context)));`
 
This solution fails because `std::bind` pass bound arguments as lvalues, rather than rvalue. `fixed_f` is a good solution.

If you have to pass rvalue-reference as bound argument, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871273/passing-rvalues-through-stdbind) will help.